# Adding an activity to the stack when the application is in the background

Tags: android, android-activity

Suppose the user is in the activity `A` of my application.
The user leave the application (with the home button) and at some point, while he is doing something else, I want to change the stack of my application to `A B`. I do not want the activity `B` to pop up from nowhere, I just want that when (if) the user returns to my application, he sees the activity `B`.

It seems that calling `startActivity(B)` in the activity `A` from a background thread works, but I’m not sure this will have the desired behaviour on every platform (what I want is that the user does not see the activity `B` until he returns to my application)

Answer (score 0):

I may not be following this correctly

If all you are after is saving state (which activity was last active) you could use preferences [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

You could then just have a MainActivity that does nothing other than decide which activty should be displayed the next time your application starts

Main

Using preferences find the last activity that was active
  Start first activity dependent last activity ID or whatever logic you choose

Activity A or B starts/resumes etc - Store activity ID in shared preferences for retrieval later

Comment: In my application there are threads doing stuff, and a thread may receive something from the network which should start the activity `B` from the activity `A`. Now, if the user has temporarily left my application and the threads are still running, I do not want to agress the user by showing `B` out of nowhere, I just want to add `B` to the stack of the currently running task of my application. The user should then see `B` when he returns to my application.